# How to setup ngrok for coldfusion 11

Tags: coldfusion

I want to test my application built in coldfusion 11 through ngrok because I have integrated twilio api in my applicaton ,need to test whether it is working with twilio api or not.can anyone help me?.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your best solution is to look at [CommandBox](https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox) and then the CommandBox module [box-ngrok](https://www.forgebox.io/view/box-ngrok).

Comment: Thank you Richard Herbert I'll go through it.

Comment: Didn't know they had a module for that. Learn something new every day....

Comment: @Richard Herbert when I start commandbox server by typing "start server" command it starts up on localhost with random port but not showing server admin page It says "forbidden" instead on browser.

Comment: May I suggest you read the documentation for CommandBox as noted above. You can also join the CFML Slack Workspace for more interactive support - http://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/